# Deactivated wifi drivers, now they won't activate again on a Dell Mini 10v?

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.04

I have ubuntu 13.04.

In the software and update menu, under additional drivers, Were it says "Broadcom Corporation; BCM4312 802.11b/gLP.PHY" the box labbeled "do not use it ticked" and when i try tick the one that says "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA Wireless drivers....." it wont let me apply changes, it starts doing it then stops and re-ticks the do not use box.

Because of this I can not use the wiress driver. Is there another way i can fix this.
Or maby restore ubuntu to previous date.

I accidentally ticked the do not use box this morning and now can't undo it. 
I have restarted several times to try apply changes and still no luck

Comment: Restart your computer to apply the changes. It is likely the drivers are broken, so Ubuntu deactivated them.

Comment: I have restarted and still no luck

Comment: Does Ubuntu say the drivers are broken?

Comment: Above the boxes that say "Do not use the device" and "Using Broadcom 802.11....." Its says This device is not working. It was all fine half an hour ago

Comment: Are you using a PCI enabled card?

Comment: I don't know, I have a Dell Inspiron mini 10v, if that helps.. Do you know if i can activate the wifi driver from the terminal or something.

Comment: Ubuntu is probably deactivating it because it is broken. Go [here](http://www.stchman.com/ath_drv.html) for instructions on how to install a working open-source driver.

Comment: With a working ethernet connection, do: sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source

Comment: After deciding to reinstall few hours ago I just did something similar, I plugged in my ethernet cable and ran `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and it fixed it straight away. Thanks to the two of you above who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

OP posted:

> After deciding to reinstall few hours ago I just did something similar, I plugged in my ethernet cable and ran `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` and it fixed it straight away. Thanks to the two of you above who tried to help.